# readsocket: Connection reset by peer (WSAECONNRESET) (10054)

Tags: windows-7, http, ssl, stunnel

I'm using stunnel to tunnel SSL traffic to port 80. And up until today it's been working just fine. And indeed for a good amount of pages on my website it still works just fine but for some pages it just doesn't. I can't say for sure but it seems like it's mainly those pages where I'm trying to make an HTTP POST.

Here are the stunnel logs:

```
2013.04.04 18:57:57 LOG5[2184:2416]: https accepted connection from 192.168.1.1:65099
2013.04.04 18:57:57 LOG5[2184:2416]: https connected remote server from 127.0.0.1:1182
2013.04.04 18:57:57 LOG3[2184:2416]: readsocket: Connection reset by peer (WSAECONNRESET) (10054)
2013.04.04 18:57:57 LOG5[2184:2416]: Connection reset: 0 bytes sent to SSL, 4290 bytes sent to socket
```

The problem isn't the web server either because I can post on port 80 just fine - I just can't do so via SSL/TLS.

Also, for reference, here's what it looks like when a good connection is made (for an HTTP GET request):

```
2013.04.04 19:30:42 LOG5[2184:3392]: https accepted connection from 192.168.1.1:65465
2013.04.04 19:30:42 LOG5[2184:1112]: https accepted connection from 192.168.1.1:65466
2013.04.04 19:30:42 LOG5[2184:1116]: https accepted connection from 192.168.1.1:65467
2013.04.04 19:30:42 LOG5[2184:3392]: https connected remote server from 127.0.0.1:1204
2013.04.04 19:30:42 LOG5[2184:1112]: https connected remote server from 127.0.0.1:1205
2013.04.04 19:30:42 LOG5[2184:1116]: https connected remote server from 127.0.0.1:1206
2013.04.04 19:30:43 LOG5[2184:1116]: Connection closed: 33734 bytes sent to SSL, 4365 bytes sent to socket
2013.04.04 19:30:43 LOG5[2184:1112]: Connection closed: 576 bytes sent to SSL, 386 bytes sent to socket
2013.04.04 19:30:45 LOG5[2184:4064]: https accepted connection from 192.168.1.1:65464
2013.04.04 19:30:45 LOG5[2184:1984]: https accepted connection from 192.168.1.1:65463
2013.04.04 19:30:45 LOG5[2184:4064]: https connected remote server from 127.0.0.1:1208
2013.04.04 19:30:45 LOG5[2184:1468]: https accepted connection from 192.168.1.1:65462
2013.04.04 19:30:45 LOG5[2184:1984]: https connected remote server from 127.0.0.1:1209
2013.04.04 19:30:45 LOG5[2184:1468]: https connected remote server from 127.0.0.1:1210
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind...  I figured it out. The problem was specific to that computers Google Chrome. It worked in other Google Chrome installs on other computers - just not that one. I cleared the history until the beginning of time and the website worked again on that computer.

No idea how the history (or cache or whatever component of the history that it was) was causing this issue..